# Polygon overlap, specific case

Tags: polygon, overlap

I've implemented a function to check the overlapping of two polygons, p1 and p2, to verify if p1 overlaps p2 the function takes every edge of p1 and test if one point of it is inside p2 and not on an edge of p2 (they can share an edge).

The function works just fine, the problem is that it's called a thousand times and it makes my program really slow since it have to iterate through each edge point by point and I'm only checking 4 cases of polygon overlapping, they are:

If a triangle overlaps a triangle.

If a triangle overlaps a rectangle.

If a triangle overlaps a parallelogram.

If a rectangle overlaps a parallelogram.

Is there any simpler and faster way to check if these cases of overlapping occur?

Comment: You should state if you search a pixel based algorith, or a vector based, it seems that you now are pixel based.

Comment: If looking for a point means it is pixel based than it's pixel based.

Comment: A point is a pair of coordinates, which can be of type double: (3.545, 123.222) like geographic coordinates, which are geo points. Or the can be of type int, further points can be limited to screen size, or the can be limited by Integer.MAX_VALUE which all makes a difference....

Comment: Hmm, I'm using doubles for the coordinates.

Comment: You can use double that avoids conversion evry time from integer to double , but practicaly they are integral values (screen coordinates?) or?

Comment: edited with the info about the polygon representation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking all you are really looking for is where [line segment intersections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection). This can be done in O((N+k) log N), where N is the number of line segments (roughly the number of vertices) and k is the number of intersections. Using the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm. This would probably be best done using ALL of the polygons, instead of simply considering only two at a time.

The trouble is keeping track of which line segments belong to which polygon. There is also the matter that considering all line segments may be worst than simply considering only two polygons, in which case you stop as soon as you get one valid intersection (some intersections may not meet your requirements to be count as an overlap). This method is probably faster, although it may require that you try different combinations of polygons. In which case, it's probably better to simply consider all line segments.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the intersection test by first check if the edge intersects the boundin box of the polygon. Look at Line2D.interSects(Rectangle2D rect).

If you have ten thousands of polygons, then you further can speed up, by storing the polygons in a spatial index (Region Quadtree). This then will limit the search to a view polygons instead of bruite force searching all. But this proably make only sense if you often have to search, not only once at program start up.

Comment: My description is correct, to iterate an edge AB (from A to B) I take the first point and then iterate through it checking if have to travel it horizontally(add 1 or -1 on X coordinate) , vertically (add 1 or -1 on Y coordinate) or diagonally ( add on both coordinates).

Comment: Are you suggesting to check only the endpoints? But if I do that the overlapping check might fail since the endpoints might not be inside the other polygon but just a part of the edge.

Comment: If coordinates are in double you cannot simply add "add 1 or -1 on X coordinate" This would only be valid if the overlapping is related to overlapping on screen.